# Laravel Class 'App\Modules\ServiceProvider' not found?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Hello Friends I am new in Laravel framework.

i create modules directory in app folder.

then i also create ServiceProvider.php file in modules directory.

my file structure like.

```
app\modules\ServiceProvider.php
```

This is code of ServiceProvider.php.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Modules;

abstract class ServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

public function boot() {
    if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
        $this->package("app/" . $module, $module, app_path() . "/modules/" . $module);
    }
}

public function register() {

    if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
        $this->app["config"]->package("app/" . $module, app_path() . "/modules/" . $module . "/config");

        // Add routes
        $routes = app_path() . "/modules/" . $module . "/routes.php";
        if (file_exists($routes))
        require $routes;
    }
}

public function getModule($args) {
    $module = (isset($args[0]) and is_string($args[0])) ? $args[0] : null;
    return $module;
}

}
```

Then i create a new points directory in modules directory.

and also create ServiceProvider.php file in points directory.

This is ServiceProvider.php file code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Points;

class ServiceProvider extends \App\Modules\ServiceProvider {

public function register() {
parent::register("points");
}

public function boot() {
parent::boot("points");
}

}
```

Then now i try to load project i got error like.

```
Class 'App\Modules\ServiceProvider' not found 

 Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­app/­modules/­points/­ServiceProvider.php5
```

i also add autoload entery in composer.json file like.

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    "app/modules"
   ]
 },
```

Then also run this command.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

but then after is not work.

i also register my ServiceProvide in app.php like.

```
'providers' => array(
       'App\Modules\Points\ServiceProvider'
 ),
```

please tell where i doing a mistake.

thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I try run your code, and everything works great.

It's a new installation of Laravel 4.1

**Obs.: check your** `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'App\\Modules\\Points\\ServiceProvider' => $baseDir . '/app/modules/points/ServiceProvider.php',
    'App\\Modules\\ServiceProvider' => $baseDir . '/app/modules/ServiceProvider.php',
    'BaseController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/BaseController.php',
    'DatabaseSeeder' => $baseDir . '/app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php',
    'HomeController' => $baseDir . '/app/controllers/HomeController.php',
    'IlluminateQueueClosure' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/IlluminateQueueClosure.php',
    'SessionHandlerInterface' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/http-foundation/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Resources/stubs/SessionHandlerInterface.php',
    'TestCase' => $baseDir . '/app/tests/TestCase.php',
    'User' => $baseDir . '/app/models/User.php',
);
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
      "app/modules",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

**app.php**

```
<?php
'providers' => array(

  'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
  'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
  'App\Modules\Points\ServiceProvider'
  ),
```

**app/modules/points/ServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Modules\Points;

class ServiceProvider extends \App\Modules\ServiceProvider {

  public function register() {
    parent::register("points");
  }

  public function boot() {
    parent::boot("points");
  }

}
```

**app/modules/ServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Modules;

abstract class ServiceProvider extends \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider {

  public function boot() {
    if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
      $this->package("app/" . $module, $module, app_path() . "/modules/" . $module);
    }
  }

  public function register() {

    if ($module = $this->getModule(func_get_args())) {
      $this->app["config"]->package("app/" . $module, app_path() . "/modules/" . $module . "/config");

        // Add routes
      $routes = app_path() . "/modules/" . $module . "/routes.php";
      if (file_exists($routes))
        require $routes;
    }
  }

  public function getModule($args) {
    $module = (isset($args[0]) and is_string($args[0])) ? $args[0] : null;
    return $module;
  }

}
```

Comment: @renishkhunt your code is the same as mine? Check your `autoload_classmap.php`

Comment: Thanks for the `autoload_classmap.php`, after looking in there I figured I was modifying the wrong composer.json

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue.

The problem was in the file: `./bootstrap/cache/config.php`

I have removed it and everything starts to work: `rm ./bootstrap/cache/config.php`

My infrastructure located in docker I have run that command in the PHP container.

Comment: This worked for me. Using artisan commands to clear the cache would fail every time, but deleting these files worked.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to `composer.json` autoload section:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
}
```

and then `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: maybe try `psr-0` instead. `psr-4` won't work unless you have current version of Composer. So eighter `psr-0` or `composer self-update`

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty newbie in creating a package. The first time after I created the following structure, I put it in Vendor folder.

```
qplot
    environment-color
        src
            config
            QPlot
                EnvironmentColor
                    ColorServiceProvider.php
                    EnvironmentColor.php
        tests
```

But soon I realized this doesn't make sense, since Laravel won't autoload all the bundles for you unless you registered it. So I moved folder to /app/vendor (new folder).

And then following Andreyco's suggestion to notify autoload path

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/vendor",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

And then when I run `php artisan dump-autoload`, and open `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, all new classes under QPlot are registered :)

Now when I go back to add the provider to Laravel `/app/config/app.php`,

```
'providers' => array(
    'QPlot\EnvironmentColor\ColorServiceProvider'
```

So the steps are

- setup your package in a folder where your git will cover
- register the autoload in composer
- composer dump-autoload
- add provider to config
- now go back to coding

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel Class ‘App\Modules\ServiceProvider’ not found**

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/", 
        "Modules\\": "Modules/"
    }
}
```

Need to add “Modules\”: “Modules/” psr-4 part in your root composer.json file

Answer (score 1):

Execute the command in your project root path

**composer dump-autoload**

Comment: Men... u r a genius!

Answer (score 0):

my initial thought was the composer autoload as well, but it didn't feel very Laravel 5ish to me. L5 makes heavy use of Service Providers, they are what bootstraps your application.

To start off I created a folder in my app directory called Helpers. Then within the Helpers folder I added files for functions I wanted to add. Having a folder with multiple files allows us to avoid one big file that gets too long and unmanageable.

Next I created a HelperServiceProvider.php by running the artisan command:

artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider or
php artisan make:provider HelperServiceProvider
Within the register method I added this snippet

```
public function register()
{
    foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
        require_once($filename);
    }
}
```

lastly register the service provider in your config/app.php in the providers array

'providers' => [
    'App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',
]
now any file in your Helpers directory is loaded, and ready for use.

UPDATE 2016-02-22

There are a lot of good options here, but if my answer works for you, I went ahead and made a package for including helpers this way. You can either use the package for inspiration or feel free to download it with Composer as well. It has some built in helpers that I use often (but which are all inactive by default) and allows you to make your own custom helpers with a simple Artisan generator. It also addresses the suggestion one responder had of using a mapper and allows you to explicitly define the custom helpers to load, or by default, automatically load all PHP files in your helper directory. Feedback and PRs are much appreciated!

composer require browner12/helpers

Answer (score 0):

Add this line top of AgentServiceProvider.php

use Agent;

like:

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Agent;
```

[Source](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent)