# Fatal error: Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, soap-client

how to fix this problem in laravel 5.1.

Did I forgot something in following this steps https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap . Also I'm a little bit confused where to put this register class alias:

```
class_alias('Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper', 'SoapWrapper');
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379554/laravel-class-app-modules-serviceprovider-not-found

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the install instructions for Laravel, not Lumen.
[as shown here](https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap)

in you app.php add the service provider and the alias as:

```
'serviceProviders' => [
...
...
'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider',
]
```

and:

```
'aliases' => [
...
...
'SoapWrapper' => 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper',
]
```

this is only for Lumen:

```
class_alias('Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper', 'SoapWrapper');
```

Comment: Now I got an error...     FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider' not found..

Comment: have you added the 
`{
    "require": {
        "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.2.*"
    }
}`
to your composer.json?

Comment: after you added this to composer.json, did you run this command?
`composer install`

Comment: yes. before adding the providers and aliases in config/app.php I run the command and it says --  Call to undefined method App\Http\Controllers\Demo\DataSoap::getAfterFilters()