# Class 'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider' not found in laravel 6.1

Tags: php, laravel

```
    /**
     * @param  string  $provider
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
     */
    public function createProvider($provider)
    {
        return new $provider($this->app);
    }
```

Comment: check your vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php

Comment: was this ever resolved? I also have this issue

Answer (score 0):

composer update' should fix your issue.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

**Server Requirements**

The Laravel framework has a few system requirements. Before we will install laravel 6.1 on windows, read some system requirements.

```
PHP >= 7.2.0
BCMath PHP Extension
Ctype PHP Extension
JSON PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension
```

Comment: Hey @Akrosh , Please recheck Server Requirements , then check here this questions has already answered here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379554/laravel-class-app-modules-serviceprovider-not-found